# Send a message to all users when the bot wake up

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've started tinkering with python recently and I'm on my way to create my very first telegram bot mainly for managing my Raspberry Pi and a few things connected to it. The bot is done but I would like to send a message to all the users that have already interacted with the bot when it starts, basically saying something like "I'm ready!", but I haven't been able to find any information about it.

Is there any specific method in the API already done to do this? Or should I create another file to store the chat_id from all the users and read it with python?

Thank you all for your help!! Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any specific method in the API already done to do this?

No, there's no such method.

> Or should I create another file to store the chat_id from all the users and read it with python?

Yes, you should handle it yourself. Usually user ids and another information about `User <-> Bot` interaction is stored in a database on a server, because it's easier for maintaining and searching.

So if you want to send a plain text message to your users in a file, you should call [`SendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method of telegram bot API for every user in your file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the database solution, I think it's better and more scalable.

Answer (score 8):

You should have a Database that stores Chat-id(s) of  Clients that interact with your bot.
If you're able to put them into a list, then the job is half done.
All you need to do is to create a "for loop", and send message to all the ID(s) in the list.
Example:

```
message = "Good morning"
chats =[1234447488,3748838477,4748848578,7463638488]
for chat in chats:
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat,text= "message")
```

In case of of clients that have deleted your bot, you may experience an error. You can catch that with `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 1):

You should save users in database or file.After that use for to send_message one by one to all users that you have in database or file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should create another file or use a database to store the chat_id of all the users you interact with. You can check [Telegram Bots API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) to see all the available commands. if there is no such command then there probably won't be any command in the wrapper you are using for python either.